# What does that fact that $AB = I_3$ tell us about $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have to two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that, $A \in \mathbb{R^{3 \times 4}}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R^{4 \times 3}}$.

> What does that fact that $AB = I_3$ tell us about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What does it mean when two numbers $a, b$ exist such that $ab = 1$?

Comment: I think that means that they are invertible. However if $A$ has 4 columns and 3 rows but $B$ has 3 columns and 4 rows, then individually they are not invertible. So what does mutually invertible mean?

Comment: If $A$ has 4 columns and 3 rows, then $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 4}$, not $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 3}$.

Comment: @almagest That is just wrong. Consider
$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\cr0&1&0&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr}$$
and $B=A^T$. we have $AB=I_3$ but they are not mutual inverses. $BA$ is the diagonal matrix with three $1$s and a single $0$ along the diagonal. Also, only square matrices can have inverses.

Comment: @MorganRodgers true. But at the time I wrote it, nothing was said about the sizes of $A,B$. That edit came later. However, I have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, it could mean various things, for example:

**Note 1:** $AB=I_3$ tells you exactly what the rank of $A$ is. There is only ONE value the rank of $A$ can take, and conversely, given a matrix of that rank you can always find such a $B$.

**Note 2:** $AB=I_3$ is equivalent to $T_A \circ T_B =Id$, and for functions this is equivalent to $T_A$ being onto and $T_B$ being one-to-one.

**P.S.** Hopefully, this makes the relation more clear:

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be the cannonical basis in $\mathbb R^3$ and $v_i =Ae_j$.
Then $v_1,v_2,v_3$ must be linearly independent in $\mathbb R^3$.

Next, fix a vector $w$ such that $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3, w \}$ are linearly independent.

Then, $AB=I_3$ if and only if there exists some $v \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $B$ is the only matrix with 
$$Bv_1=e_1 \\Bv_2=e_2 \\ Bv_3=e_3 \\
Bw=v$$

$B$ exists and is unique because of the above linear independence.

*Geometrically* $T_A$ is a bijection between $\mathbb R^3$ and a subspace $V \subset \mathbb R^4$. Then $T_B$ must be the inverse of this mapping from $V \to \mathbb R^3$, extended arbitrarily from $V \subset \mathbb R^4$ to the entire $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Exactly. There are various implications however the question that I was asked was "How are the two matrices related?". So I'm not sure if there is a specific answer to this or not.

Comment: @riceee The linear transformations relation says that $T_B$ is a right inverse of $T_A$. Since $T_A$ is one to one, but not onto, the restriction of $T_B$ to the range of $A$ has to be the inverse, but $T_B$ can be ANYTHING, in the orthogonal direction of the range.

Comment: Can it be determined that both matrices are pseudo inverses?

Comment: @ricee If $AB=I$ then $BAB=BI=B$ and $ABA=IA=A$....